# UWP: Using Cloud image FilePath Access Denied

Tags: c#, image, cloud, uwp

I'm using a file picker to select an image to use in my app. I save the filepath then in other pages of the app, I display the image from the filepath. When the image is on the device, it works. If the image is on the cloud, the file path:

"C:\Data\Users\DefApps\AppData . . .\TempState\ShareCache\IMG_1613.jpg"

Gives me an error message that access is denied.

One solution I can think of is once the image is selected making a copy of the image to the device so that the filepath would be accessible.

Is this the best practice to handle this situation?

This is the code I'm using:

```
private async void AddPic_OnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        FileOpenPicker openPicker = new FileOpenPicker();
        openPicker.ViewMode = PickerViewMode.Thumbnail;
        openPicker.SuggestedStartLocation = PickerLocationId.PicturesLibrary;

        openPicker.FileTypeFilter.Clear();
        openPicker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".bmp");
        openPicker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".jpg");
        openPicker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".jpeg");
        openPicker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".png");

        // Launch file open picker and caller app is suspended and may be terminated
        var file = await openPicker.PickSingleFileAsync();
        if (file != null)
        {
            var loadImage = new BitmapImage();

            using (var stream = await file.OpenReadAsync())
            {
                await loadImage.SetSourceAsync(stream);
            }
            img.Source = loadImage;
            _imageFilePath= file.Path;

        }
    }
```

Comment: Which cloud service do you use? The cloud path can definitely not be something like  "C:\Data\Users\DefApps\AppData . . .\TempState\ShareCache\IMG_1613.jpg". For example, if you use Azure, you can refer to [Get started with Azure Blob storage using .NET](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/storage-dotnet-how-to-use-blobs/).

Comment: My cloud service is what comes default on the phone. Whenever I set up a microsoft account on a windows phone my photos are uploaded onto the cloud automatically. I had to do a reset on my phone & my pictures were removed but whenever I looking my photo gallery it shows the images on the cloud. Whenever I use my app, it pulls the file path of the image to be reused. Whenever the image is on the cloud, i get the file path I provided in the question. I ended up turning showing the cloud images off in my settings, but this will be something ill need to fix.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to your description, you may be using [OneDrive](https://dev.onedrive.com/index.htm) on your PC/ phone.

> "C:\Data\Users\DefApps\AppData . . .\TempState\ShareCache\IMG_1613.jpg"

this is a system level folder for storing cache file , we shouldn’t/cannot access it through the file picker in an app.

For your scenario, one solution is like what you said, download the image, or you can develop your app with [OneDrive API](https://dev.onedrive.com/README.htm), or more easier, if you allow syncing files on your device, you can access Microsoft OneDrive folder with file picker.